# How do I draw a curly arrow diagram for the oxidation of primary alcohol to an aldehyde and subsequently to a carboxylic acid?

Tags: alcohols, organic-oxidation

I've determined the chemical equations for both the mechanisms, but I'm unable to draw curly arrow diagrams for the two reactions using potassium dichromate as the oxidising reagent. I'm not sure how to go about doing this, and I can't seem to find anything online related to do this.

From what I've studied,
oxidation of primary alcohol to aldehyde:

$$\ce{3CH3CH2OH + Cr2O7^2- + 8 H+ -> 3CH3CHO + 2 Cr^3+ + 7 H2O}$$

and, oxidation of primary alcohol to carboxylic acid:

$$\ce{3CH3CH2OH + 2Cr2O7^2- + 16 H+ -> 3CH3COOH + 4 Cr^3+ + 11 H2O}$$

I've found information pertaining to drawing curly arrow diagrams for the oxidation of secondary alcohols to ketones, but I'm unable to apply the same to my query.

Comment: What was the oxidation agent in the examples? Could you draw curly arrows for the reaction $\ce{CH3CH2OH -> CH3CHO + H- + H+}$? Or $\ce{CH3CH2OH + O2 -> CH3COOH + H2O}$? That way, you would not have to deal with the chromium chemistry and still see what is going on with the functional groups.

Comment: Do the same thing with the primary alcohol as you would for the secondary alcohol. As for the aldehyde, hydrate it first and then proceed.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49542/mechanism-of-the-oxidation-of-alcohols-with-kmno4