# Mechanism of alkyl benzene reaction with KMnO4/KOH to form carboxylic acids

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image: alkylbenzene]

I came across this reaction regarding formation of carboxylic acid by treating alkylbenzenes with KMnO4/KOH.
I know that alpha-(C-H) bond in this compound is easily broken down into radicals. Then it reacts to form

[image: 1st step]

After this step mysteriously manganese reactions to form phenylmethanoic acid and all remaining alkyl carbon are oxidized to CO2
I want your help to understand the mechanism of this reaction and how manganese reacts further down the reaction.

Comment: this answer at least partially answers your question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49542/mechanism-of-the-oxidation-of-alcohols-with-kmno4

Comment: i tried this exact mechanism but end product is alkylphenylketone but in above reaction which i mentioned end product is benzene carboxylic acid. I want a mechanism of this reaction to understand how reactions occurs and why certain product is favored over other.

Comment: Work through the mechanism with one of the R groups being H so that the aldehyde is formed. Remember that aldehydes readily form hydrates in aq environments.

Comment: i did the thing you are recommending and we do get a aldehyde but the original reaction has R group as alkyl so i can't just do that. But what i want is actual mechanism which explains why even the alkyl groups are converted to CO2 and how that occurs.